# Locked ATR stop loss

Tags: cryptography, pine-script, pine-script-v4, forex

I want to know how to add a STATIC ATR. I can only find pine script for a ATR trailing stop loss. So does anyone now how i can add a static atr to my already existing strategy?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a `var` variable to store the ATR value in memory.

For example, if you want to store the ATR value when you enter a trade so you can use this in your TP/SL calculations, you would do something like below:

```
var float atr_at_entry = na

atr_val = ta.atr(14)

atr_at_entry := is_new_position ? atr_val : atr_at_entry  // If it is a new position store the atr_val in atr_at_entry. Keep its value otherwise

// Use atr_at_entry in your TP/SL calculations
```